# How can I get a count of files in a directory using the command line?

Tags: command-line

I have a directory with a large number of files. I don't see a `ls` switch to provide the count. Is there some command line magic to get a count of files?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9157138/recursively-counting-files-in-a-linux-directory

Comment: `tree . | tail` or `tree -a . | tail` to include hidden files/dirs, `tree` is recursive if that's what you want.

Comment: @CodyChan : It should be `tail -n 1`, and even then the count would also include the entries in subdirectories.

Answer (score 446, accepted):

Using a broad definition of "file"

```
ls | wc -l
```

(note that it doesn't count hidden files and assumes that file names don't contain newline characters).

To include hidden files (except `.` and `..`) and avoid problems with newline characters, the canonical way is:

```
find . ! -name . -prune -print | grep -c /
```

Or recursively:

```
find .//. ! -name . -print | grep -c //
```

Comment: `wc` is a "word count" program. The `-l` switch causes it to count lines.  In this case, it's counting the lines in the output from `ls`.  This is the always the way I was taught to get a file count for a given directory, too.

Comment: please add note that `ls` does `ls -1` if the output is a pipe.

Comment: that doesn't get everything in a directory - you've missed dot files, and collect a couple extra lines, too. An empty directory will still return 1 line. And if you call `ls -la`, you will get three lines in the directory. You want `ls -lA | wc -l` to skip the `.` and `..` entries. You'll still be off-by-one, however.

Comment: An empty directory returns 0 for me

Comment: If you have a file whose name contains a newline, this approach will incorrectly count it twice.

Comment: A corrected approach, that would not double count files with newlines in the name, would be this: `ls -q | wc -l` - though note that hidden files will still not be counted by this approach, and that directories will be counted.

Comment: How does this work? I need to know how to modify it slightly / combine recursion with including hidden files. Even a link would be nice.

Comment: Wow I can't believe that something so easily done in Windows with "dir" can be so cumbersome with Linux :|

Comment: "ls -1 | wc" counts files.  dash-one (-1) flag for 'ls' is an easy way to get a single file per line.

Answer (score 52):

For narrow definition of file:

```
 find . -maxdepth 1 -type f | wc -l
```

Comment: And you can of course omit the `-maxdepth 1` for counting files recursively (or adjust it for desired max search depth).

Comment: If you have a file whose name contains a newline, this approach will incorrectly count it twice.

Comment: A corrected approach, that would not double count files with newlines in the name, would be this: `find -maxdepth 1 -type f -printf "\n" | wc -l`

Comment: +1  Allow for hidden files and ignores directories

Answer (score 35):

I have found `du --inodes` useful, but I'm not sure which version of `du` it requires. It should be substantially faster than alternative approaches using `find` and `wc`.

On Ubuntu 17.10, the following works:

```
du --inodes      # all files and subdirectories
du --inodes -s   # summary
du --inodes -d 2 # depth 2 at most
```

Combine with `| sort -nr` to sort descending by number of containing inodes.

Comment: no `--inodes` on FreeBSD :(

Comment: Thanks for sharing! I searched for "count" in the `du` man page, as in "I want to count the files", but it's not documented with that word. Any answer using `wc -l` will be wrong when any name contains a newline character.

Comment: `du --inodes` include `.` (or `..`?) as a dir, so the count should minus 1. For example I have a dir with only jpg files, `du --inodes` gives me 200 while `ll *.jpg | wc -l` gives me 199

Answer (score 22):

```
ls -1 | wc -l
```

...

```
$ ls --help | grep -- '  -1'
    -1                         list one file per line
```

...

```
$ wc --help | grep -- '  -l'
    -l, --lines            print the newline counts
```

PS: Note ls -<number-one> | wc -<letter-l>

Comment: Most versions of `ls` do `-1` automatically when the output is to a pipe.

Comment: @Dennis that's interesting I didn't know that an application could tell its output was going to a pipe.

Comment: I +'ed this version since it is more explicit.  Though, yes ls does use -1 if it's piped (try it:  ls | cat), I find the -1 syntax more explicit.

Comment: @xenoterracide: In Bash: `[[ -p /dev/stdin ]] && echo "stdin is from a pipe"`

Comment: In my tests it was significantly faster to also provide the -f option to avoid ls sorting the filenames.  Unfortunately you still get the wrong answer if your filenames contain newlines.

Comment: Doesn't account for hidden (".") files.

Answer (score 16):

Probably the most complete answer using `ls`/`wc` pair is

```
ls -Aq | wc -l
```

if you want to count dot files, and

```
ls -q | wc -l
```

otherwise.

- `-A` is to count dot files, but omit `.` and `..`.
- `-q` make `ls` replace nongraphic characters, specifically newline character, with `?`, making output 1 line for each file

To get one-line output from `ls` in terminal (i.e. without piping it into `wc`), `-1` option has to be added.

(behaviour of `ls` tested with coreutils 8.23)

Comment: As you said, `-1` is not needed. As to _"it handles newlines in filenames sensibly with console output"_, this is because of the `-q` switch (that you should use instead of `-b` because it's portable) which _"Forces each instance of non-printable filename characters and <tab> characters to be written as the <question-mark> ( '?' ) character. Implementations may provide this option by default if the output is to a terminal device."_ So e.g. `ls -Aq | wc -l` to count all files/dirs or `ls -qp | grep -c /` to count only non-hidden dirs etc...

Comment: Thanks for your input. Changed `-b` to `-q`.

Comment: Currently includes directories in its file count. To be *most complete* we need an easy way to omit those when needed.

Comment: @JoshHabdas It says "probably". ;) I think the way to omit directories would be to use don_crissti's suggestion with a slight twist: `ls -qp | grep -vc /`. Actually, you can use `ls -q | grep -vc /` to count all (non-hidden) files, and adding -p makes it match only regular files.

Answer (score 9):

If you know the current directory contains at least one non-hidden file:

```bsh
set -- *; echo "$#"
```

This is obviously generalizable to any glob.

In a script, this has the sometimes unfortunate side effect of overwriting the positional parameters. You can work around that by using a subshell or with a function (Bourne/POSIX version) like:

```bsh
count_words () {
  eval 'shift; '"$1"'=$#'
}
count_words number_of_files *
echo "There are $number_of_files non-dot files in the current directory"
```

An alternative solution is `$(ls -d -- * | wc -l)`. If the glob is `*`, the command can be shortened to `$(ls | wc -l)`. Parsing the output of `ls` always makes me uneasy, but here it should work as long as your file names don't contain newlines, or your `ls` escapes them. And `$(ls -d -- * 2>/dev/null | wc -l)` has the advantage of handling the case of a non-matching glob gracefully (i.e., it returns 0 in that case, whereas the `set *` method requires fiddly testing if the glob might be empty).

If file names may contain newline characters, an alternative is to use `$(ls -d ./* | grep -c /)`.

Any of those solutions that rely on passing the expansion of a glob to `ls` may fail with a *argument list too long* error if there are a lot of matching files.

Comment: Do you really want to create 13,923 positional parameters? And you should make your local variable `local` or eliminate it: `eval $1=$#` or just use `echo $#` and do `number_of_files=$(count_words *)`.

Comment: @Dennis: part of the point was to avoid forking. I guess that's not a 21st century concern. Ok, I admit I don't care about non-POSIX shells any more, so I could have avoided the temporary variable.

Comment: Why did you subtract one from `$#` (you hadn't done that prior to the edit)?

Comment: @Dennis: I'm still avoiding a fork (well, it does make a difference on machines with a slow CPU such as routers) and passing a variable name as `$1`. So what I want to count is the number of parameters that aren't the first parameter. (I can't use `shift` because I need to keep the variable name around.) (Umm, now if you'd asked about the *first* line...)

Comment: @Dennis: come to think of it, I can use `shift` if I time it right.

Comment: *facepalm* - I overlooked the fact that you were passing a variable reference and needed to deduct for that. /renews *Weekly Reader* subscription

Answer (score 9):

With the GNU implementation of `find`:

```
find -maxdepth 1 -type f -printf . | wc -c
```

- `-maxdepth 1` will make it non-recursive, `find` is recursive by default
- `-type f` will include regular files only
- `-printf .` is a cute touch. it prints a dot (a single-byte character in every locale) for each file instead of the filename, and now this is able to handle any filename and also saves data; we just have to count the dots :). Note however that `-printf` is a GNU-only extension.
- `| wc -c` counts bytes and reports the total as a decimal integer (possibly preceded and/or followed by whitespace depending on the `wc` implementation, not with GNU `wc`)

Answer (score 5):

While using ls/wc pair if we are adding -U it will be much faster (do not sort ).

```
ls -AqU | wc -l
```

Comment: `-U` is GNU-specific though.

Answer (score 3):

After installing the tree command, just type:

`tree`

If you want hidden files too:

`tree -a`

If you are using Debian / Mint / Ubuntu Linux, type the following command to install the tree command:

`sudo apt-get install tree`

The option -L is used for specifying the maximum display level of the directory tree. The tree command does not only count the number of files, but also the number of directories, considering as many levels of the directory tree as you like.

Comment: When I type tree, I get a sort of tree output to the screen of the directory I am in but I cannot see where the number of files is shown.

Answer (score 2):

No pipe, no string copy, no fork, just plain bash one liner

```bsh
$ fcount() { local f i=0; for f in *; do let i++; done; echo $i; }; fcount
```

Comment: Gives a value of 1 if no files in directory.  Doesn't count files, counts files and directories.

Comment: But this method works when other methods fail with: -bash: /usr/bin/ls: Argument list too long

Answer (score 2):

With some shells, you can do that without relying on external utilities:

### fish

```
count *
```

Or to include hidden files:

```
count * .*
```

### zsh

Define a function, here called `count` to mimic `fish`'s builtin:

```
count() print $#
```

Then call the function with:

```
count *(N)
```

Or use an *anonymous* function:

```
(){print $#} *(N)
```

To include hidden (`D`ot) files:

```
(){print $#} *(ND)
```

You could also add a `oN` glob qualifier to disable sorting,
or add `.`, `/` or `@`...
to count only *regular* files, *directories* or *symlinks*...

Replace `*` with `**/*` to also count files in sub-directories recursively.

## ksh93

```
count() print "$#"
count ~(N)*
```

To include hidden files:

```
count ~(N){.,.[!.],..?}*
```

Or:

```
(FIGNORE=.:..; count ~(N)*)
```

### bash

```
count() { echo "$#"; }
(shopt -s nullglob; shopt -u failglob; count *)
```

To include hidden files:

```
(shopt -s nullglob dotglob; shopt -u failglob; count *)
```

Answer (score 1):

Here's another technique along the lines of the [one Gilles posted](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/1125/how-can-i-get-a-count-of-files-in-a-directory-using-the-command-line/1133#1133):

```
word_count () { local c=("$@"); echo "${#c[@]}"; }
file_count=$(word_count *)
```

which creates an array with 13,923 elements (if that's how many files there are).

Comment: What's the point of that `c` array? `word_count() { echo "$#"; }` would be enough. The point of @Gilles solution is to store the count in a returned variable to avoid having to use command substitution (which involves a fork and pipe in shells other than ksh93).

Answer (score 1):

On Linux, to make the command very robust and handle files that might have newlines in their name, use this:

```
find -maxdepth 1 -type f -print0 | tr -cd '\0' | wc -c
```

This saves us from the [ordeal](https://mywiki.wooledge.org/ParsingLs) of parsing `ls` output.

---

Related:

- [Count nul delimited items in file](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/164988/201820)

Answer (score 0):

```
find . -type f -maxdepth 1 |  wc -l
```

This can list only the files in current directory.

Comment: `find . -type f` will find files in the current directory, and also, recursively, in sub-directories.

Answer (score 0):

Improving some answers given before but this time doing explicitly.

```
$ tree -L 1 | tail -n 1 | cut -d " " -f 3
```

It's worthy to notice the use of some loved commands like `tail` and `cut`. 
Also, note that tree is not available by default. The command above first capture information about the directory at level 1, then get the last line `tail -n 1` where our goal is, and end up with `cut` to take the third word.

For instance, locating in `/`:

```
/ $ tree -L 1
.
├── 1
├── bin -> usr/bin
├── boot
├── dev
├── etc
├── home
├── lib -> usr/lib
├── lib64 -> usr/lib64
├── lost+found
├── media
├── mnt
├── opt
├── proc
├── root
├── run
├── sbin -> usr/sbin
├── srv
├── sys
├── tmp
├── usr
└── var

20 directories, 1 file
/ $ tree -L 1 | tail -n 1
20 directories, 1 file
/ $ tree -L 1 | tail -n 1 | cut -d " " -f 3
1
```

Then, what about asking the number of directories?

Answer (score 0):

If you have rights to install packages, there is a very simple tool to do this (and more). It is called `ncdu` and it can be installed using apt or yum. A basic usage of ncdu would be:

```
ncdu /path/to/dir
```

This will display an ncurses-based screen which you can navigate using cursor keys. At the bottom, initially you will see the total number of files in that directory and subdirectories. Using the up/down arrow keys and ENTER, you can quickly navigate to any directory and get stats on  usage.

A slightly advance use is `ncdu -x /path/to/dir` which will count only those files and directories which are on the same filesystem as the directory being scanned.

A bonus of ncdu is that it gives a progress bar while scanning. You can also redirect the output to a file for later use.

In the man page, there is an interesting section on how hard links are handled across various versions of ncdu.

HTH.

Answer (score 0):

I use this one, few examples:

```
ls -Ap    directory01/directory02  | grep -v /$  | wc -l
ls -Ap    directory01/directory02/exampl*  | grep -v /$  | wc -l
ls -Ap    /home/directory01/directory02  | grep -v /$  | wc -l
```

It works like this:

- `-p` with `ls` adds `/` at the end of the directory names.
- `-A` with `ls` lists all the files and directories, **including** hidden files but **excluding** `.` and `..` directories.
- `grep -v /$` only shows the lines that **do not** match (`-v` option) lines that end with `/`. (directories)
- `wc -l` counts the number of lines.

Either I use for example mix of these:

```
ls -Ap    directory01/directory02  | grep -v /$  | wc -l ; /
ls -Ap    directory01/directory02/exampl*  | grep -v /$  | wc -l; /
ls -Ap    /home/directory01/directory02  | grep -v /$  | wc -l
```

So, for example from the:

```
$ tree
.
├── directory01
│   ├── directory02
│   ├── directory03
│       ├── Screenshot from 2022-04-19 15-12-55.png
│       └── Screenshot from 2022-04-19 16-05-05.png
│       └── directory04
```

I will get count [**plain files**]

```
$ ls -Ap    directory01/directory03  | grep -v /$  | wc -l 
2
```

It will be counted both

```
│       ├── Screenshot from 2022-04-19 15-12-55.png
│       └── Screenshot from 2022-04-19 16-05-05.png
```

but no [*not a **plain** file*]

```
directory04
```

Comment: (1) Please don’t pipe `grep` into `wc -l` unless you have some reason for not using ``grep -c``.  (2) If you use a wildcard (glob), you should use the `-d` option of `ls`.  (3) What in the world is that second block of commands?  (4) Directories *are* files.  The question doesn’t say that it’s asking for the number of ***plain** files.*  If you want to provide that, you should say that that’s what you are doing. … (Cont’d)

Comment: (Cont’d) …  (5) This is little more than a rehash of comments by [don_crissti](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/1125/80216#comment341977_189824) and [Frax](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/1125/80216#comment1091705_189824), and a few answers.   It’s (arguably) OK to take somebody else’s comment and post it as an answer, but only if you give credit to the people who posted it first.

Comment: Sure. Thanks for Comment. Ad.1. If anything else would work to get what *exactly* I need I would use stg different, but so far very only this command gives me what *I* want. Ad 4. ok, ok, edited about **plain** files Ad.5. It is already in TWO places written about it, do you want it in a very first sentence or where?

Answer (score 0):

To build on [James' answer](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/1126/278372), you can write something like this to achieve a breakdown of all the direct subdirectories.

```bash
tree -aFid -L 1 . | while read f; do if [[ -d "${f}" ]]; then echo -en "${f}: "; find "${f}"//. ! -name . -print | grep -c //; fi; done
```

Output:

```
.: 884
documents: 46
photos: 300
videos: 138
```

I've just managed to quickly find the one directory that contained missing files after a file transfer that way.

Answer (score -2):

Try this  i hope this answer will help you

```
echo $((`ls -l | wc -l` -1 ))
```

Answer (score -2):

You can check with:

```
ls -l | grep -v ^l | wc -l
```

Answer (score -3):

Use the `tree` command, just:

```
tree
```