# What's the best way to count the number of files in a directory?

Tags: shell, files, directory, ls, wildcards

If parsing the output of `ls` is dangerous because it can break on some funky characters (spaces, `\n`, ... ), what's the best way to know the number of files in a directory?

I usualy rely on `find` to avoid this parsing, but similarly, `find mydir | wc -l` will break for the same reasons.

I'm working on Solaris right now, but I'm looking for a answer as portable across different unices and different shells as possible.

Comment: I'm not sure it's a duplicate, am I missing something?

Comment: This might be a duplicate, but not of the question indicated. `find` will get you number of files recursively (use `-maxdepth 1` if you don't want that. `find mydir -maxdepth 1 -type f -printf \\n | wc -l` should handle the special characters in the filename, as they are never printed in the first place.

Comment: Looks like a duplicate of  [How can I get a count of files in a directory using the command line?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/1125/how-can-i-get-a-count-of-files-in-a-directory-using-the-command-line)

Answer (score 21, accepted):

How about this trick?

```
find . -maxdepth 1 -exec echo \; | wc -l
```

As portable as `find` and `wc`.

Comment: This doesn't work (it displays `n+1` files on my Debian system). It also doesn't filter for regular files.

Comment: I just gave a generic example. It does work, but *how* it works depends on how you adapt the `find` command to your specific needs. Yes, this one includes all the directories, including `.` (which might be why you see the result as `n+1`).

Comment: I like this trick, very clever; but I'm surprised there's no simple straightforward way to do that!

Comment: @ChrisDown the OP doesn't specify filtering for regular files, asks for number of files in a directory.  To get rid of the n+1 issue, use `find . -maxdepth 1 ! -name . -exec echo \; | wc -l`; some older versions of `find` do not have `-not`.

Comment: Note that `-maxdepth` is not standard (a GNU extension now also supported by a few other implementations).

Answer (score 13):

In bash, without external utilities, nor loops:

```
shopt -s dotglob
files=(*)
echo "${#files[@]}"
```

In ksh, replace `shopt -s dotglob` by `FIGNORE=.?(.)`. 
In zsh, replace it by `setopt glob_dots`, or remove the `shopt` call and use `files=(*(D))`. (Or just drop the line if you don't want to include dot files.)

Portably, if you don't care about dot files:

```
set -- *
echo "$#"
```

If you do want to include dot files:

```
set -- *
if [ -e "$1" ]; then c=$#; else c=0; fi
set .[!.]*
if [ -e "$1" ]; then c=$((c+$#)); fi
set ..?*
if [ -e "$1" ]; then c=$((c+$#)); fi
echo "$c"
```

Comment: The first example prints `1` for an empty directory when `nullglob` is not enabled. In zsh, `a=(*(DN));echo ${#a}` with the `N` (`nullglob`) qualifier does not result in an error for an empty directory.

Answer (score 10):

```
find . ! -name . -prune -print | grep -c /
```

Should be fairly portable to post-80s systems.

That counts all the directory entries except `.` and `..` in the current directory.

To count files in subdirectories as well:

```
find .//. ! -name . | grep -c //
```

(that one should be portable even to Unix V6 (1975), since it doesn't need `-prune`)

Comment: One of the rare portable answers on this page, if not the only one.

Comment: I upvoted this answer yesterday as I found it also works well for directories other than the current directory (`find dirname ! -name dirname -prune -print`). I have since been wondering if there's any particular reason to use `grep -c /` instead of `wc -l` (which is probably more commonly used for counting).

Comment: `find dirname ! -name dirname` doesn't work if there are other directories within that are named `dirname`. It's better to use `find dirname/. ! -name .`. `wc -l` counts the number of lines,  file names can be made of several lines as the newline character is as valid as any in a file name.

Answer (score 8):

Try:

```
ls -b1A | wc -l
```

The `-b` will have non-printable characters, `-A` will show all files except `.` and `..` and one per line (the default on a pipe, but good to be explicit).

As long as we're including higher-level scripting languages, here's a one-liner in Python:

```
python -c 'import os; print len(os.listdir(os.sep))'
```

Or with full 'find':

```
python -c 'import os; print len([j for i in os.walk(os.sep) for j in i[1]+i[2]])'
```

Answer (score 2):

The most simple version I use all the time and never had problems with is:

`ls -b1 | wc -l`

Comment: You might run into problems if the file name contains a `\n` or other funky chars (yeah, certain unices allow this).

Comment: I tried this explicitly before posting my answer and had no problems with it. I used nautilus file manager to rename a file to contain \n to try this.

Comment: You'r right it doesn't work like that. I don't know what I did when I tested this first. Tried again and updated my answer.

Comment: No, the command is OK, but there is already a similar solution and hidden files are not counted.

Comment: `ls -1 | wc -l` fine on OpenBSD ksh

Answer (score 1):

Yoc can use such construction:

```
I=0; for i in * ; do ((I++)); done ; echo $I
```

But I'm afraid, you can cath error like `Argument list too long.` in case you have too many files in directory. However I tested it on directory with 10 billion files, and it worked well.

Comment: THis won't work for hidden files either unless the shell is configured to expand those with `*`.

Comment: `gnu find . -maxdepth 1 -type f | wc -l`

Comment: @Rush: this command should never raise "arg list too long". That only happens with external command (so never with `for`.

Answer (score 1):

Have you considered perl, which should be relatively portable?

Something like:

```
use File::Find;

$counter = 0;

sub wanted { 
  -f && ++$counter
}

find(\&wanted, @directories_to_search);
print "$counter\n";
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this => Using *ls* with -i ( for node number ) & -F (appends directory name with '/' ) options.

```
ls -ilF | egrep -v '/' | wc -l
```

Answer (score 0):

With a `perl` one-liner (reformatted for readability):

```perl
perl -e 'opendir($dh, ".");
         while ( readdir($dh) ) {$count++};
         closedir $dh;
         print "$count\n";'
```

or

```perl
perl -e 'opendir($dh, ".");
         @files = readdir($dh);
         closedir $dh;
         print $#files+1,"\n";'
```

You can use `perl` functions that modify arrays like `grep` or `map` with the second version.  See `perldoc -f readdir` for an example using `grep`.

Answer (score 0):

In addition to the `find`-based answer [proposed by Stéphane](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/202415/203203), here is a POSIX-compliant answer based on `ls`:

```
ls -qf | tail -n +3 | wc -l
```