# save the number of files only in a specific folder

Tags: bash, shell, shell-script, files

I'm using this script to save the number of files in a main folder, but it also counts the subfolders inside that main folder.
`nfiles=$(ls -1 /home/userA/mainfolder | wc -l)` Any advice how I can modify it to only include files not folders?

Comment: `find . -maxdepth 1 -type f | wc -l` ([don't parse `ls`](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/ParsingLs))...

Comment: @jasonwryan I tried this one `nfiles= find /home/userA/mainfolder -maxdepth 1 -type f | wc -l` but it says `bash: /home/userA/mainfolder: is a directory 0`

Comment: `nfiles=$(find . -maxdepth 1 -type f | wc -l) && echo "$nfiles"`

Comment: @jasonwryan this includes hidden files as well, is it possible to only include visible files? Also please post it as an answer to accept it :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Rather than [parsing `ls`](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/ParsingLs), you can use `find`:

```
find . -maxdepth 1 -type f ! -name ".*" | wc -l
```

This will find all files (`-type f`) in the current directory (`.`) except those beginning with a . (`! -name ".*"`) and pass the result to `wc` to count the lines.

To use it as a variable in your script:

```
nfiles=$(find . -maxdepth 1 -type f ! -name ".*" | wc -l)
```

Comment: @mikeserv you should make that an answer.

Comment: How, exactly, is this superior to "parsing `ls`"?  One of the big issues with parsing the output from `ls` is that filenames can contain newlines.  Well, won't `find … -print | wc -l` fail in exactly the same way as `ls | wc -l`?  Hint: see [this](http://unix.stackexchange.com/a/27498/80216) and [this](http://superuser.com/a/689326/354511).

Answer (score 3):

Don't use `find` for this.

Besides requiring non-portable GNU extensions to make it work, it also has to `stat()` every file for which it searches. `ls`, on the other hand, can simply list the current directory's dentries out `-1` per line while `-q`uoting all non-printables with a ? question mark *(to include `\n`ewlines)*, and appending a `/` for each directory listing.

That way for a simple `-c`ount of non-dotfiles in the current directory you can just do:

```
ls -1pq | grep -c -v /
```

And the entire process is not only likely faster than `find` would be, it is also POSIXly done.