# Understanding find(1)'s -exec option (curly braces & plus sign)

Tags: find

Using the following command, could someone please explain what exactly is the purpose for the ending curly braces ({}) and plus sign (+)?

And how would the command operate differently if they were excluded from the command?

```
find . -type d -exec chmod 775 {} +
```

Answer (score 39, accepted):

The curly braces will be replaced by the results of the `find` command, and the `chmod` will be run on each of them. The `+` makes `find` attempt to run as few commands as possible (so, `chmod 775 file1 file2 file3` as opposed to `chmod 755 file1`,`chmod 755 file2`,`chmod 755 file3`). Without them the command just gives an error. This is all explained in [`man find`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/find.1.html):

> `-exec command ;`
>
>     Execute
>     *command*
>     ; true  if 0 status is returned. 
>       All following
>                     arguments to
>     **`find`**
>     are taken to be arguments to the command until
>                     an  argument  consisting of ‘
>     `;`
>     ’ is encountered. 
>       The string ‘
>     `{}`
>     ’ is replaced by the current file name being processed  everywhere
>                     it occurs in the arguments to the command, not just in arguments
>                     where it is alone, as in some versions of
>     **`find`**
>     . …
>
> `-exec command {} +`
>
>     This  variant  of the
>     `-exec`
>     action runs the specified command on
>                     the selected files, but the command line is built  by  appending
>                     each  selected file name at the end; the total number of invocations of the command will  be  much  less  than  the  number  of
>                     matched  files. …

Answer (score 25):

In addition to terdon’s answer,

- “Obviously” `-exec …` must be terminated with either a semicolon (`;`)
  or a plus sign (`+`).  Semicolon is a special character in the shell
  (or, at least, every shell I’ve ever used),
  so, if it is to be used *as part of the `find` command*,
  it must be escaped or quoted (`\;`, `";"`, or `';'`).
- With `-exec … ;`, the `{}` string may appear
  any number of times in the command, *including zero*,
  or two or more, in any position. 
  <sup>See [this](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/27498/80216)
  for an example of why you might want to do `-exec` without using `{}`.</sup> 
  Having two or more appearances is useful principally
  because, in (at least) some versions of `find`,
  the `{}` doesn’t need to be a word by itself;
  it can have other characters at the beginning or end; e.g.,

  ```
  find . -type f -exec mv {} {}.bak ";"
  ```

  With `-exec … +`,
  the `{}` string ***must*** appear as the last argument before the `+`. 
  A command like

  ```
  find . -name "*.bak" -exec mv {} backup_folder +
  ```

  results in the enigmatic `find: missing argument to ‘-exec’` error message.

  - A workaround for this that’s specific to the `cp` and `mv` commands is

    ```
    find . -name "*.bak" -exec mv -t backup_folder {} +
    ```

    or

    ```
    find . -name "*.bak" -exec mv --target-directory=backup_folder {} +
    ```

  The `{}` must be a word by itself;
  it cannot have other characters at the beginning or end. 
  And, in (at least) some versions of `find`,
  you may not have more than one `{}`.
- A sanity note: You can say

  ```
  find . -name "*.sh" -type f -executable -exec {} optional args here ";"
  ```

  to run each of your scripts.  But

  ```
  find . -name "*.sh" -type f -executable -exec {} +
  ```

  runs *one* of your scripts, with the names of all the others as parameters. 
  This is similar to saying

  ```
  ./*.sh
  ```

  as a shell command,
  except `find` does not guarantee that it sorts its results,
  so you aren’t guaranteed of running `aaa.sh`
  (your alphabetically first `*.sh` file)
  as you would be with running `./*.sh`.
- An aspect of `find` that may not be perfectly clear to beginners is
  that the command line is, effectively,
  an *executable statement* in an arcane language. 
  For example,

  ```
  find . -name "*.sh" -type f -executable -print
  ```

  means

  ```
  for each file
      if the file’s name matches `*.sh` (i.e., if it ends with `.sh`)
      then
          if it is a plain file (i.e., not a directory)
          then
              if it is executable (i.e., the appropriate `---x--x--x` bit is set)
              then
                  print the file’s name
              end if
          end if
      end if
  end loop
  ```

  or, simply,

  ```
  for each file
      if the file’s name matches `*.sh`  AND  it is a plain file  AND  it is executable
      then
          print the file’s name
      end if
  end loop
  ```

  Some of the `-` keywords are both an executable action and a test. 
  In particular, this is true for `-exec … ;`; for example,

  ```
  find . -type f -exec grep -q cat {} ";" -print
  ```

  translates to

  ```
  for each file
      if it is a plain file (i.e., not a directory)
      then
          execute         grep -q cat filename
          if the process succeeds (i.e., exits with status 0)
          then
              print the file’s name
          end if
      end if
  end loop
  ```

  which will print the names of all files containing the string “`cat`”. 
  And, while this is something that `grep` can do by itself
  (with the `-l` (lower-case `L`) option), it can be useful
  to use it with `find` to find files that contain a certain string
  AND have a certain size AND are owned by a certain owner
  AND were modified in a certain time range, ….

  However, this does not work for `-exec … +`. 
  Since `-exec … +` executes one command for multiple files,
  it doesn’t make sense to use it as a logical condition
  inside a `for each file …` loop.
- The flip side of the above is that `find` generally exits
  with an exit status of 0 unless you give it invalid arguments
  or it encounters a directory that it can’t read. 
  Even if a program that you execute fails
  (exits with a non-zero exit status),
  `find` will exit with an exit status of 0. 
  ***Except*** if a program that you execute with `-exec … +` fails
  (exits with a non-zero exit status),
  `find` will exit with a non-zero exit status.

In addition to a million versions of `find(1)`
and testing what `find` actually does on a couple of systems,
[The Open Group Base Specifications Issue 7, 2013 Edition](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799)
provided some of the information on what `find` must, may, and must not do.

Comment: Beware that your example using `... -exec mv {} {}.bak  ...` is not guranteed to work as expected with all `find` implementations. The POSIX standard states `{}` must appear alone to be always recognized, otherwise the behavior is free to keep the characters unchanged or to replace them by the pathname. In the former case, your whole command will essentially delete all files but the last one found...