# What is the meaning of "\;" in "find" command?

Tags: find

What is the meaning of  `\;`  in  `find`  command? What is the reason to use it?

In manual I can find example:

```
find . -type f -exec file '{}' \;
```

Why not:  `find . -type f -exec file '{}'`  ?

Comment: Related: [Understanding the -exec option of `find`](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/389705/understanding-the-exec-option-of-find) , [Understanding find(1)'s -exec option (curly braces & plus sign)](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/202391/understanding-find1s-exec-option-curly-braces-plus-sign)

Answer (score 2):

The `find` command has to have a way of telling where the command that should be executed through `-exec` ends.  Without the `;` at the end of the command, `find` would not know where the command ended and where (possibly) other `find` flags continued.

A nonsensical example that executes `basename` on all files and `ls` on all directories:

```
find . '(' -type f -exec basename {} ';' ')' -o '(' -type d -exec ls {} ';' ')'
```

Without the `;` above, `find` would not know whether to execute `basename /some/path` or `basename /some/path ')' -o '(' ...` etc.

Quoting or escaping the `;` is only done so that the shell will not treat it as a command delimiter.

A less nonsensical example that first copies `.txt` files to a particular directory and then renames the original files by appending `.done` to their name (if the copying went ok):

```
find . -type f -name '*.txt'
    -exec cp {} /some/path/dest ';' \
    -exec mv {} {}.done ';'
```

(Note, as Eliah Kagan points out in comments, that the construct `{}.done` is strictly speaking not portable, but *implementation defined*. An implementation may choose not to expand the `{}` characters to the current pathname, or it may do.  In my experience, all `find` implementations *do* expand `{}` to the current pathname even when concatenated with another string like this.)

Without the `;` in the previous example, `find` would not know whether we would want to execute the `cp` command on the found file together with `/some/path/dest`, a file called `-exec`, `mv` etc.

Comment: I'm not sure why this has been downvoted. It addresses the question of why `;` can't simply be omitted very well. But it occurs to me that another purpose of `;` is to tell `find` to run the command separately with each path, rather than pass multiple paths to the command as with `+`. (Also, arguments like `{}.done` [aren't *strictly* portable](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/find.html); there, "it is implementation-defined whether find replaces those two characters or uses the string without change." I don't regard this as a problem but it may be worth mentioning.)