# How to create a file for every directory on a tree?

Tags: touch, tree

For the following tree structure:

```
    .
└── dir1
    └── dir2
        └── dir3
```

What would be a simple way to create a file (could be empty), for every directory, so the resulting tree will look like:

```
.
├── dir1
│   ├── dir2
│   │   ├── dir3
│   │   │   └── README
│   │   └── README
│   └── README
└── README
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do that with find:

```
find . -mindepth 1 -type d -exec touch "{}/README" \;
```

**Explanation**

- `-mindepth 1` will set the minimum depth, to avoid including the current directory
- `-type d` will only find directories
- `-exec` will run a command
- `{}` contains the path of the found directory

If you want to use only builtin shell commands:

```
for dir in *; do if [ -d "$dir" ]; then touch "$dir/README"; fi; done
```

**Explanation**

- `for` will loop over every element in `*`, meaning all files in the current directory. `dir` will contain the current element during the loop.
- `if [ -d $dir ]` checks if the element is a directory and only then
- creates a file called `README` in the directory name contained in `$dir`

Comment: Note that arguments that include (contain) `{}` as a substring are not guaranteed to work.

Comment: @G-ManSays'ReinstateMonica' could you name one example where that would fail?

Comment: I can’t give *specific* examples where it would fail, but see (1) [Wildcard’s answer](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/321697/80216#321753) — scroll down to “**`find` in combination with `sh`**” and read the second bullet. Or see (2) [jlliagre’s comment](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/202391/understanding-find1s-exec-option-curly-braces-plus-sign/202409#comment505495_202409) on [my answer](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/202391/80216#202409). … (Cont’d)

Comment: (Cont’d) … In an attempt to get specific, I’d say that you’re depending on behavior that may be unique to GNU ``find``, so you’d be in danger on any busybox-based system (e.g., ESXi), or on non-Linux systems like \*BSD, HP-UX, Solaris, etc.

Answer (score 3):

With `zsh`:

```
touch -- README **/*(N/e[REPLY+=/README])
```

It combines [*recursive globbing*](https://zsh.sourceforge.io/Doc/Release/Expansion.html#Recursive-Globbing) (`**/*`) with [*glob qualifiers*](https://zsh.sourceforge.io/Doc/Release/Expansion.html#Glob-Qualifiers), which here are:

- `N`ullglob: doesn't trigger an error if there's no match.
- `/`: restrict to files of type *directory*
- `e[code]`: `e`valuates the `code` for each file, here appending `/README` to file path (stored in `$REPLY` in the evaluated code).

Or you could use an [*anonymous function*](https://zsh.sourceforge.io/Doc/Release/Functions.html#Anonymous-Functions) which is passed the list of directories, and which appends the `/README` to each in the arguments it passes to `touch`:

```
() {touch -- $^@/README} . **/*(N/)
```

(with [*rc-style array expansion*](https://zsh.sourceforge.io/Doc/Release/Expansion.html#index-array-expansion-style_002c-rc) for the anonymous function `@`rguments using the `$^array` syntax).

In all those, you can add the `D`otglob glob qualifier to also add `README` to hidden directories.

Comment: Could you add an explanation to your answer?

Comment: @mashuptwice, see edit.