# Is there a more succinct alternative to piping to wc for counting files in a directory

Tags: ubuntu, command-line, filesystems

If I do `ls -1 target_dir | wc -l`, I get a count of files in a directory. I find this a bit cumbersome. Is there a more elegant or succinct way?

Comment: You don't need the "-1" when piping to wc.

Comment: `ls` already gives the total count, so how about `ls -l | head -1`? Make it an alias if you want something shorter.

Comment: @DanielWagner The "total: nnn" output by `ls -l` indicates the total size of the files, not the number of files.

Comment: Keep in mind that `ls | wc -l` will give you the wrong count if any file names contain newlines.

Comment: This depends of file-system, and counts directories + 2 in a directory. The answer has 2 extra ( as it counts itself, and its parent).

`stat -c %h .` gives the same information as `ls -ld . | cut -d" " -f 2`

Comment: http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/1125/how-can-i-get-a-count-of-files-in-a-directory-using-the-command-line

Answer (score 12):

Assuming bash 4+ (which any supported version of Ubuntu has):

```
num_files() (
    shopt -s nullglob
    cd -P -- "${1-.}" || return
    set -- *
    echo "$#"
)
```

Call it as `num_files [dir]`. `dir` is optional, otherwise it uses the current directory. Your original version does not count hidden files, so neither does this. If you want that, `shopt -s dotglob` before `set -- *`.

Your original example counts not only regular files, but also directories and other devices -- if you really only want regular files (including symlinks to regular files), you will need to check them:

```
num_files() (
    local count=0

    shopt -s nullglob
    cd -P -- "${1-.}" || return
    for file in *; do
        [[ -f $file ]] && let count++
    done
    echo "$count"
)
```

If you have GNU find, something like this is also an option (note that this includes hidden files, which your original command did not do):

```
num_files() {
    find "${1-.}" -maxdepth 1 -type f -printf x | wc -c
}
```

(change `-type` to `-xtype` if you also want to count symlinks to regular files).

Comment: Won't `set` fail if there are very many files? I think you might have to use `xargs` and some summing code to make that work in the general case.

Comment: Also `shopt -s dotglob` if you want files starting with `.` to be counted

Comment: @l0b0 I don't think `set` will fail under these circumstances, since we're not actually doing an `exec`. To wit, on my system, `getconf ARG_MAX` yields 262144, but if I do `test_arg_max() { set -- {1..262145}; echo $#; }; test_arg_max`, it happily replies 262145.

Comment: @DavidRicherby `-maxdepth` is not POSIX.

Comment: @l0b0 `set` is a shell builtin, it does not suffer from `ARG_MAX` restrictions.

Comment: potentially more elegant. Definitely not more succinct. And not as obvious as other solutions.

Comment: @MichaelMartinez Writing obvious code is not a substitute for writing correct code.

Comment: @ChrisDown I didn't know that about shell builtins. Thanks!

Comment: @ChrisDown I don't wan't to interfere in the discussion on code correctness, but hasn't that solution a memory usage proportional to the number of files (if one consider an average name length) ?

Comment: @ChrisDown: OP specifically asks for elegant and succinct.

Comment: @l0b0 I was trying to explain what Chris Down said more succinctly. The `ARG_MAX` restriction is an error given by the `exec` family of functions – it's not a feature of the shell per se, any any command that doesn't `exec` would not suffer from the limitation. Shell builtins are the most common example of commands that take arguments but don't `exec`.

Comment: +1 for the `find` solution. It deals correctly with special filenames (like ones with line breaks in it).

Answer (score 3):

`f=(target_dir/*);echo ${#f[*]}`

works correctly for file with spaces, newlines, etc. in the name.

Comment: can you provide some context? Should this go in a bash script?

Comment: it could. you could also put it directly in the shell. that version assumed you wanted the current directory; i've edited it so it's closer to your question. basically it creates a shell array variable containing all the files in the directory, then prints the count of that array. should work in any shell with arrays -- bash, ksh, zsh, etc. -- but probably not plain sh/ash/dash.

Answer (score 2):

`ls` is multi-columns only if it outputs directly to a terminal, you can remove the "-1" option, You can remove the `wc` "-l" option, only read the first value (lazy solution, not to be used for legual evidences, criminal investigations, mission critical, tactical ops..).

```
ls target | wc
```

Comment: This fail for filenames containing newlines.

Comment: @Emmanuel You'll need to parse the result of your `wc` to get the number of files in even the trivial case, so how is this even a solution?

Comment: @Emmanuel This can fail if `target` is a glob which, when expanded, includes some things that start with hyphens. For example, make a new directory, go into it and do `touch -- {1,2,3,-a}.txt && ls *|wc` (NB: use `rm -- *.txt` to delete those files.)

Comment: Did you mean `wc -l`? Otherwise you get newline, word, and byte counts of the `ls` output. That is what David Richerby said: You have to parse it again.

Comment: @erik I ment `wc` with no argument you don't need to parse if your brain knows that the first argument is newline.

Answer (score 2):

If it's succinctness you're after (rather than exact correctness when dealing with files with newlines in their names, etc.), I recommend just aliasing `wc -l` to `lc` ("line count"):

```
$ alias lc='wc -l'
$ ls target_dir|lc
```

As others have noted, you don't need the `-1` option to `ls`, since it's automatic when `ls` is writing to a pipe. (Unless you have `ls` aliased to always use column mode. I've seen that before, but not very often.)

An `lc` alias is quite handy in general, and for this question, if you look at the "count the current directory" case, `ls|lc` is about as succinct as you can get.

Answer (score 2):

So far Aaron's is the only approach more succinct than your own. A more correct version of your approach might look like:

```sh
ls -aR1q | grep -Ecv '^\./|/$|^$'
```

That recursively lists all files - not directories - one per line including .dotfiles beneath the current directory using shell globs as necessary to replace non-printable characters. grep filters out any parent directory listings or .. or */ or blank lines - so there should only be one line per file - the total count of which grep returns to you. If you want child directories included as well do:

```sh
ls -aR1q | grep -Ecv '^\.{1,2}/|^$'
```

Remove the `-R` in either case if you do not want recursive results.

Comment: I tend to prefer to do that kind of thing with `find`. If you only want a count, this should work: `find -mindepth 1 -maxdepth 1 -printf '\n'|wc -l` (remove the depth controls to get recursive results).

Comment: @AaronDavies - that doesn't actually work. Put a newline in any of those filenames and see for yourself. Also, to do the same thing portably you do: `find . \! -name . -prune | wc -l` - which still doesn't work, of course.

Comment: I don't follow -- the `printf` instruction prints a constant string (a newline) that doesn't include the filename at all, so the results are independent of any strange filenames. This trick can't be done at all with a `find` which doesn't support `printf`, of course.

Comment: @AaronDavies - oh, true. I assumed the filename was included. It can be done portably, though, of course: `find .//. \!. -name . -prune | grep -c '^\.//\.'`

Comment: brilliant! `/` being the only other character that can't appear in filenames, the `.//.` sequence is guaranteed to appear exactly once for every file, right? a couple questions though -- why `.//.`, and why `-prune`? when would this differ from `find . \! -name . | grep -c '^\.'`? (i assume the `.` in your `\!.` is a typo.)

Comment: @AaronDavies - the `-prune` is to keep from recursing. The `/` can appear in soft-links, but `find` doesn't list them that way. Its spec'd to report paths a certain way, and so you can rely on the spec in such a way that you can contort the output in simple, one-off ways that accomplish your goal. its why the spec is so important - in order to reliably do a thing you need to know reliably and up front what it won't do first.