# How do I get a count of files in a directory (recursively) but exclude directories with a certain name

Tags: find

This is very similar to [this](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/1125/how-can-i-get-a-count-of-files-in-a-directory-using-the-command-line?newreg=ac019316ae274cd7bc2b9021b328881c) question, but I need to take it a bit further.  I'm using a synology drive and there are tons of `@eaDir` directories which I want to ignore (and the files in those directories).  How can I do that?

Here's a recursive command that works great with hidden files (which I want)...but how do I alter this to exclude directories names `@eaDir`?

```
find .//. ! -name . -print | grep -c //
```

Comment: Why don't you use the `-prune` option as indicated in the accepted answer in the post you link to?

Comment: I just can't get the syntax working:  find .//. ! -name @eaDir -prune -print | grep -c //

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you don't want to descend into any of the directories named `@eaDir` then you should not use `!` before `-name`:

```
 mkdir -p a/@eaDir
 mkdir -p b/c/@eaDir
 mkdir -p d/e/f
 touch a/@eaDir/xxx
 touch b/yyy
 touch b/c/@eaDir/xxx
 touch d/e/f/yyy
 find . -name '@eaDir' -prune -o -print
```

will give you:

```
.
./b
./b/yyy
./b/c
./a
./d
./d/e
./d/e/f
./d/e/f/yyy
```

and

```
find .//. -name '@eaDir' -prune -o -print | grep -c //
```

will give you: `9`

If the name matches `-name '@eaDir'` then the rest of the tree underneath is skipped ('-prune') otherwise the name is printed (`-o -print`)

Comment: With the `!` ( which works as not ...) the toplevel would get pruned and you end up with 0