# Using .sh file to return the number of files in a directory

Tags: bash, shell-script, files

I have written the script below but it returns 0 for the number of files in the directory now matter how many files are in the directory.

```
source ~/Alan/assign/changeDir.sh
num=$(( ls | wc -l ))
echo $num
```

changeDir.sh script is the following

```
function my_cd() {
cd ~/Alan
}
```

All I need is a number to be returned in order for it to be used later in the same script. I would very much appreciate guidance on this. Thanks

Comment: Do you, by the word "file", mean "regular files", or just any files?

Answer (score 3):

To find the number of names in a single directory, expand the `*` glob in it and count the number of generated words:

```
shopt -s nullglob    # to make the * glob expand to nothing
                     # if there is no matching names
set -- *
num=$#

printf '%s\n' "$num"
```

The special value `$#` is the number of positional parameters.  The `set` command sets the positional parameters.

Would you want to count *regular* files only, and include hidden names, then use

```sh
shopt -s nullglob dotglob

for name in *; do
    if [ ! -f "$name" ] || [ -L "$name" ]; then
        # skip non-regular files and symbolic links
        continue
    fi
    files+=( "$name" )
done

num=${#files[@]}

printf '%s\n' "$num"
```

To do that recursively into subdirectories, also set the `globstar` shell option and use `**/*` as the globbing pattern.

(in the `zsh` shell, it would be enough with `set -- **/*(.DN); print $#`)

The issue with your

```
num=$(( ls | wc -l ))
```

is twofold:

1. `$(( ... ))` is an arithmetic expansion. You probably want a command substitution here, `$( ... )`.
2. The `wc -l` will not count files.  It will count the number of newline characters outputted by `ls`.  A file with one or more newlines in its name will be counted as multiple files by `wc -l`. You can test this by creating such a file using `touch $'hello\nworld'`.

Comment: @pLumo Yes, I chose to write it in this way as that would be what `ls` by default displays too (used by the user in the question).

Comment: @pLumo Added a bit about that.

Answer (score 2):

If you want to count files including hidden files (`.*`) , but have subdirectories excluded, you can use:

```
find . -maxdepth 1 -type f -printf '.' | wc -c
```

All benefits of `find` may be used.

Answer (score 0):

I think the problem is a wrong syntax in your command substitution.

The command

```
num=$(( expression ))
```

will interpret the content of the parentheses as an *arithmetic* expression and assign the numerical result to `num`. It will *not* return the output of running that which is written inside the parentheses as code. Rather, `ls`, `wc` and `l` will be interpreted as shell variables, and the operation "`$ls` OR `$wc` minus `$l`" be performed, which results in zero as none of these "variables" are initialized.

What you are probably trying to do would be written as

```
num="$(ls | wc -l)"
```

However, even so, [parsing the output of `ls`](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/128985/why-not-parse-ls-and-what-to-do-instead) is not a good idea in general. Rather, look at some of the answers to [this similar question](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/1125/how-can-i-get-a-count-of-files-in-a-directory-using-the-command-line) where "robust" solutions are presented that will also work when filenames contain special characters.