# Getting the first file in a directory in bash

Tags: bash, shell-script

How do you get the first file in a directory in bash? First being the what the shell glob finds first.

My search for getting the first file in a directory in bash brought me to an [old post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14509806/command-line-find-first-file-in-a-directory) with a very specific request. I'd like to document my solution to the general question for posterity and make a place for people to put alternative solutions they'd like to share.

Comment: By "file", do you mean "regular file", or are you also interested in directories, symbolic links and other types of files?

Comment: Good point. I was only considering regular files.

Comment: What do you mean by "the first" file?  First to be added to the directory, or first chronologically or as sorted using `$LC_COLLATE`, or something else?

Answer (score 29):

To get the first file in the current dir you can put the expansion in an array and grab the first element:

```
files=(*)
echo "${files[0]}"
# OR
echo "$files" # since we are only concerned with the first element
```

Assuming your current dir contains multiple dirs you can loop through and grab the first file like so:

```
for dir in *; do
    files=($dir/*)    
    echo "${files[0]}"
done
```

But be aware that, depending on your shell settings, `files=(*)` may return an array of one element (that is '*') if there are no files. So you have to check that the file names in the array correspond to files which actually exist (and bear in mind that `*` is a valid file name).

Comment: This gives you the first _name_ from the lexicographically sorted list of non-hidden names in the current directory. This may not be a regular file. In comments to the question, you [specifically asked about regular files](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/583156/getting-the-first-file-in-a-directory-in-bash#comment1155075_583156), though.

Comment: any idea why such a simple scenario is so complicated. I asked chatGPT and gave me 
`mv "$(ls | head -n 1)" /path/to/target/directory/` which lists 2 files

Answer (score 2):

Almost is an [this
answer](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/583099/72304):

```
shopt -s nullglob
set -- *
printf "%s\n" "$1"
```

Or:

```
(( $# )) && printf "%s\n" "$1"
```

To skip printing anything if there's no non-hidden file in the current working directory.

Answer (score 2):

In `zsh`:

- first non-hidden file in locale collation order: `first=(*(N[1]))`
- same, but restricted to non-directory files: `first=(*(N^/[1]))`
- same, but also excluding symlinks to directories: `first=(*(N^-/[1]))`
- restricting to *regular* files: `first=(*(N.[1]))`
- same but including symlinks to regular files: `first=(*(N-.[1]))`

Some more notes:

- those define an *array* variable as it still needs to be able to store a *variable* number of elements: 0 (no matching file) or 1 (matching files, among which only the first is selected). To define a `$first` scalar variable instead (and have it contain the empty string if there's no matching file), you can do `(){ first=$1; } *(N[1])` instead. Or to leave the `$first` scalar variable untouched instead if there's no matching file: `(){ (($#)) && first=$1; } *(N[1])`.
- to include hidden files, add the `D` glob qualifier
- in some locales (including most of the ones typically used on GNU systems from 2020 like `en_US.UTF-8`), collation order is not always deterministic as some characters sort the same. See for instance after `touch`      on Ubuntu 20.04. All those files will have the same sorting order, so which one you'll get first will be more or less random.
- with zsh glob qualifiers, it's also possible to change the order: `n` makes the filename comparison numerical (so that `file2` comes before `file10` for instance), and with the `o` (`O` for reverse) glob qualifiers, one can sort based on other criteria than name (such as age, size or even arbitrary shell code...).

Answer (score 2):

All existing answers seem to first create a full listing of the directory, which can take a while with thousands of elements, so I ended up with the simple:

```
ls -AU | head -1
```

Where `-U` means unsorted and thus produces an immediate result.

Comment: This also returns names that may not be regular files. Note that `-U` is a non-standard GNU extension. Using `find . ! -name .` may be better, but you still would only get the first part of the name if it contains newlines since `head` acts on _text_, not filenames.

Comment: You can use `-f`, seems to do the same and is standard. Filetypes are not a requirement here, but one could filter using `file` and `test` if needed. As for newlines, one can use `--zero` in ls, `-z` on head and `-print0` on find (or use its `exec` flag).

Answer (score 1):

To get the name of the regular file that sorts first in a directory, you may use

```bsh
shopt -s nullglob dotglob
unset -v name

for name in some/path/*; do
    [ -f "$name" ] && break
    unset -v name
done
```

After this loop, `$name` would either be the name of the regular file that sorts first, or the variable would be unset if there are no regular files in the directory `some/path`.

The shell options used here make sure that the loop is not run if the pattern does not match (`nullglob`), and that we also match hidden names (`dotglob`).

You'll get the first name since filename globbing patterns are expanded into lexicographically sorted lists.

Answer (score 0):

Solution using only 'find':

```
find  /tmp  -type d -exec find {}  -depth -maxdepth 1 -type f -print -quit \;
```

This will print the first filename, including path, for every directory in /tmp.

```
 find /tmp  -type d -exec find {} -depth -maxdepth 1 -type f ! -name '.*' -print -quit \;
```

This will print the first filename in every directory, but skip over DOT files.

Works both on Linux and Mac.